# Performance issue in SSLStream.Read

Tags: c#, stream

I am using the below code snippet to read the data from a stream. Here, I am using a do-while loop to read the data from a stream to get the complete data.

When  loop executes second time, the below read operation is taking almost 5 to 10 sec:

```
numberOfBytesRead = API_SSL_Stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, iBufferSize);
```

Can somebody tell me if I am missing something in the code snippet?

```
byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
SSL_Stream.ReadTimeout = 50000;
SSL_Stream.ReadTimeout = 50000;
do
{
    numberOfBytesRead = API_SSL_Stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, iBufferSize);
    if (numberOfBytesRead > 0)
    {
        myCompleteNonSensitiveMessage.Append(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        bReadComplete = false;
    }
    else
    {
      bReadComplete = true;
    }
} while (bReadComplete == false)`
```

Comment: The loop exits once you have first read operation as you set bReadComplete to false if bytes read is >0. What you can do is append a symbol at the end of the string and loop it until you find that symbol.